# Copy/Paste in PowerPoint VBA causing errors

Tags: vba, powerpoint, copy-paste

So, I've been banging my head against this one for a few days now, and figured it couldn't hurt to see if someone else has a solution.

I'm programming a macro in VBA for PowerPoint. Amongst other things, it needs to copy and paste multiple shapes (approximately 40 every time it's run). However, it randomly stops with an error:
[image: Error Message]

This happens at random points during execution, not at the same point every time; sometimes it will instead paste the previous shape, causing other issues; and sometimes it will fully execute with no problems. I have tried numerous suggested fixes that I've found here and on other sites, and nothing seems to be working.

Right now, this is the relevant bit of code:

```
ClearClipboard
newPriorityShape.Copy
DoEvents
Set pastedShp = curSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault)
ClearClipboard
```

And for ClearClipboard I have:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: I've encountered similar issues where I've told VBA to take me to a slide and select a shape. But it crashes occasionally when it doesn't get there fast enough. I've had to add if statements to test if the slide is in view. Can you check if the clipboard is empty first, or can you recreate the shape from its specs? I was also copying and pasting in the past but chose to just set the text.

Comment: This is a common problem with copy and paste as well as opening and saving files. The process takes time, but VBA doesn't. Search for Sleep, Wait and DoEvents techniques to introduce a small delay in your code. There are tons of examples out there.

Comment: One thing you could do is reference the slides and objects directly and not use do events or activate and have to wait for the program to catch up.  Heck, read your shapes into an array of objects and then add them to a PPT presentation.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit too late but I ran into the same issue recently. The implementation of the clipboard history on Windows conflicts with this, so in order to avoid those random errors you need to disable it.